# Counting the number of occurences of an event per used id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has the information, over time, of the occurences of two events (`booking` and `search`) for user ID's. It looks like this:

```
event    user_id
booking  asdf81
search   frjl22
search   frjl22
booking  frjl22
search   asdf81
```

I'd like to calculate two columns based on this - `num_bookings` and `num_searches`.

So, the output dataframe would look like this:

```
event    user_id    num_bookings   num_searches
booking  asdf81     1              0     
search   frjl22     0              1
search   frjl22     0              2
booking  frjl22     1              2
search   asdf81     1              1
```

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't quite answer my question. :(

Comment: I added an example of the result I'm looking for. I don't have any code, as I'm not sure how to do this in pandas. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not. :)

Comment: It's just an example. Is this enough to reopen the question, please? I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Let me change the input dataframe as well, then, for clarity.

Comment: OK, I've changed the input dataframe to match the order of events and user ID's in the output dataframe.

Comment: I got different output, can you explain why `0,1,2` for `frjl22` user and why `0` in last row?

Comment: Because it's cumulatively counting the number of events per user_id. So `asdf81` had 0 bookings initially, but had 1 search, so it gets a `0` and a `1`. The calculation is done from the bottom up, if it makes sense.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is my bad. The algorithm work from the the top down, in descending order. I'll amend the example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is reshape `event` column to columns and use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per all groups with removing [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then forward filling misisng values by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) with replace missing values to `0` and last add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('event', append=True)['user_id'].unstack().add_prefix('num_')
df1 = pd.concat([df1.dropna(subset=[c]).groupby(c).cumcount().add(1) 
                                             for c in df1.columns], axis=1, keys=df1.columns)
print (df1)
event  num_booking  num_search
0              1.0         NaN
1              NaN         1.0
2              NaN         2.0
3              1.0         NaN
4              NaN         1.0

df = df.join(df1.groupby(df['user_id']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
     event user_id  num_booking  num_search
0  booking  asdf81            1           0
1   search  frjl22            0           1
2   search  frjl22            0           2
3  booking  frjl22            1           2
4   search  asdf81            1           1
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately. It doesn't create the two columns, but creates a column per user_id. :(

Comment: Wait, it works now. I did something wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey, I'm so sorry, but this doesn't quite solve my problem. I don't need the total count joined straight away. I need the cumulative count. So as new events happen, the counts per user_id should be increasing. That's why they start at 0 in my example.

Comment: @neuron - Is output correct? Why in last row is `search   asdf81     1              1` ? Not is correct `search   asdf81     0              1` ?

Comment: Yes, the last row is correct. User `asdf81` first had one `booking` in the beginning, and then had one `search` at the end. So the cumulative sum of bookings is `1`, and the cumulative sum of searches is `1` as well.